# RESTful url in AppEngine dashboard

Tags: google-app-engine, dashboard

Is it possible to group RESTful URLs in AppEngine dashboard by resource? It shows /user/1 and /user/2 as different URLs and error list becomes quite useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the logs with the label filter method, in this case something like
`path: /user/.*`

You can also you `method: GET` and other filters.

Comment: Sorry, but I was asking about dashboard, not logs. I want to have overview.

Answer (score 0):

You can build this page by yourself and serve it as [custom page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Administration_console_custom_pages) in admin console.

They are showing up the info for last hour and last 24 hours, so you need to [analyze](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/#Python_Getting_log_data) logs only in that timeframe. Should be easy to implement.